# Negative left border in a div with a video inside?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the next result by adding sort of an negative border to the left side of the video and applying borders to top, right and bottom so the borders maintain at video resize.

[image]

---

**Is there any valid/good way to accomplish this with css/sass/html ?**

---

```css
.video {
      
      width: 400px;
      height: 225px;
      background-color: red;      
      position: relative;
      
}

.video video {
  
  position: absolute;
  
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>
    <section>
      <div class="video">
        <video 
        controls="controls" 
        src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
    </section>    
  </article>
</main>
```

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Please post your current HTML/CSS code to help stakeoverflow  community figuring your issue!

Comment: Setup a fiddle. We need to know how you're outputting the video

Comment: I've nothing - I just don't know to how to do such negative left: border and maintain it even at content (video) re-size. Just searching for any advice or tip that could lead me to the solution once google won't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use multiple `box-shadow` (properly adjusting the offset/colour)

```
img {
   box-shadow: 30px 0 0 0 #bbb, 30px -30px 0 0 #bbb, 30px 30px 0 0 #bbb;
}
```

Or if you want to use a Sass `mixin`:

```
@mixin rightshadow($offset, $colour) {
   box-shadow: #{$offset}px 0 0 0 #{$colour}, 
               #{$offset}px -#{$offset}px 0 0 #{$colour}, 
               #{$offset}px #{$offset}px 0 0 #{$colour};
}

img {
  @include rightshadow(25, #bbb);
}
```

> [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVVLVP)

In my example I've used an image, but of course you can apply the shadow to any other element (ie. in your example to the wrapper containing the video)

---

**Result**

[image]

Comment: you're welcome. I've edited my fiddle with a sass mixin